# What is "DataFrame object has no attribute 'ix'" error?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am just trying to run a simple code which is:

```
from stocker.stocker import Stocker
microsoft = Stocker(ticker='MSFT')
techm = Stocker(ticker='TECHM', exchange='NSE')
```

And I get this error:
[Error Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGtEx.png)

**Note:** I am a beginner at coding so please be simple in your answers.

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

Accessing rows in pandas DataFrames using `.ix` has been deprecated for some time now. Check if your `stocker` module has more recent versions than the one you have.

Comment: I got this module from github and i guess the module is no longer being updated..